# R: count the number of previous rows with the same value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have access to a data frame which contains:

- customer_id:  50K customers
- date: 200 dates *(from 1 to 200)*
- nb_visit_life_to_date:  number of life to date visits done by the customer (today or in the past).

I need to compute for each row the inactivity period known at this date, which is the number of day from the last visit to the date of the current row.

The date of the last visit can be deduced from the nb_visit_life_to_date by counting the number of previous rows with the same value.

For instance if I have 3 rows about the same user with the same numbers of Life To Date visits then I should recover for this 3rd rows an inactivity period of 2 days.

**Example with real data:**

```
input <- data.frame(
  user = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  date = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
  nb_visit_life_to_date = c(1,1,1,2,3,1,2,2,2,2)
)

output <- data.frame(
  input,
  inactivity_period_from_previous_visit = c(0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,3)
)
```

Ideally I'd like to use a `dplyr` syntax but i'm of course open to all solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward `rle` (run length encoding) task:

```
sequence(rle(input$nb_visit_life_to_date)$lengths) - 1
#  [1] 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: What if the last visit date of the nth custumer is equal to the first visit date to the n+1th customer ?
I tried to explicit a group by by using group_by in a dplyr chain `group_by(customer) %>%
 mutate( sequence(rle(.$nb_visit_life_to_date)$lengths) - 1)`  but i had this error message: `incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1`